# Configurar registro de expiracion laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo un problema, mi pagina despues de un periodo de tiempo expira, y me redirige a una pagina que ya no existe, donde puedo cambiar el tiempo y ruta de direccion en laravel?

Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el directorio `config/session.php` puedes configurar el tiempo de vida de la sesion del usuario en el parámetro `'lifetime' => X,` donde `X` es un número entero que representa los minutos que dura la sesion. Ahora lo de la re dirección si usas las clases de autenticación y los middleware que trae laravel por defecto lo puedes encontrar en `app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` en el código

```php
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
   -->     return redirect('/home');
        }
```